# What 's a good way to align layout across activities when one uses weight in linear layout while the rest does not?

Tags: android, xml

I utilized weight in the LinearLayout in the main screen of my app, but didn't do so in the other activity of my app. My goal is to align the circles and the start stop buttons in both activities, what's the best way to accomplish this? Below are my code for both activities' xml files.

Main activity that utilizes weight in LinearLayout:

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/leftTopOfApp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/topOfApp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/leftTopOfApp"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalTimeView"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:layout_below="@id/topOfApp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftTopOfApp"
        android:textSize="17sp"

        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@color/started_black"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/settingsToLinear"
        android:layout_below="@id/settings"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/settingsToLinear"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countDownView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.8"
        android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
        android:textColor="@color/started_black"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="65sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleSwitch"
        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.17"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Started activity that doesn't not utilize weight at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--layout for when timer is started-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green_go"
    android:paddingBottom="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/currentElapsed"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/green_go"
        android:textSize="65sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:background="@drawable/stop_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any advice is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate ratio of layout_weight/weight_sum for your most bottom layout ("@id/settingsToLinear").Assuming that your first activity's weight_sum 3.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green_go"
    android:paddingBottom="60dp"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        //NEEDS ID
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/currentElapsed"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/white_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/green_go"
        android:textSize="65sp"
        android:layout_weight="7" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:background="@drawable/stop_button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now both are covering 30 percent of screen.